# when booting ubuntu EXT04FS

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, ext4

when booting Ubuntu (after checking graphic card - clean)

has this error message

[image: Screen picture]

In Ubuntu 20.04

```
164.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
200.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
404.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
500.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
1635.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
3516.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
100000.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
150000.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
220000.000  EXT4-fs (sdb1) : VFS:can`t find ext4 filesystem
```

still running
and can`t use command line

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you have a missing or bad disk. However, without knowing more about your system, it will be difficult to suggest a *proper* solution. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the contents of `/etc/fstab` (2) the Terminal output of `lsblk`. With this, it *might* be feasible to suggest a way forward.

Comment: ubunru 20.04
still this state until 3days ago  and add error image